# Mysql Comparing dates stored to today's date

Tags: php, mysql

I want to go through my database datesandtime and compare them to the current date and time, and say which one is bigger.

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
$date = new DateTime();
//echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')

$query = "SELECT timedate, email  FROM mailer";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $tot = $row['timedate'];
       $ema = $row['email'];
    if($tot > $date) {
    //echo "<tr><td>" .$row['timedate']."</td><td>";
    echo"database dates higher then now dates" . "<br>";
    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['email']."</td><td>" ."<br>";
   echo "<tr><td>" .$row['timedate']."</td><td>" ."<br>";
}
else {
    echo"database dates lower then now dates" . "<br>";
    echo "<tr><td>" .$row['email']."</td><td>". "<br>";
       echo "<tr><td>" .$row['timedate']."</td><td>" ."<br>";
}

}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Here is the test output that I get:

```
database dates lower then now dates
barmaleyalex@gmail.com  
2015-05-04 08:00:00 
database dates lower then now dates
vladtheimpalor25@gmail.com  
2015-05-04 00:00:00 
database dates lower then now dates
barka@gmail.com 
2015-05-30 00:00:00
```

As you can see the last entry is wrong, its set to may 30 so it should be higher then the now date. My guess is that I'm not using the current date correctly and I need to format it.

Comment: What is the datatype of `timedate` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `timedate` is `datetime` in PHP you can simply use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
if(strtotime($tot) > time()){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first format the database result as a date before comparing them.

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
$date = new DateTime();
//echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')

$query = "SELECT timedate, email  FROM mailer";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $tot = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s",$row['timedate']);
       $ema = $row['email'];
    if($tot > $date) {
       echo"database dates higher then now dates" . "<br>";
       echo "<tr><td>" .$row['email']."</td><td>" ."<br>";
       echo "<tr><td>" .$row['timedate']."</td><td>" ."<br>";
    } else {
       echo"database dates lower then now dates" . "<br>";
       echo "<tr><td>" .$row['email']."</td><td>". "<br>";
       echo "<tr><td>" .$row['timedate']."</td><td>" ."<br>";
    }

}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant compare dates this way. You have to convert them to `timestamp` first.Try with -

```
if(strtotime($tot) > strtotime($date))
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($tot > $date)` you cannot directly compare datatime value,
you have to convert both of them time value first.

`$dateTick = strtotime($date);
$totTick = strtotime($tot);`

After that only compare

`if($dateTick < $totTick)`

Answer (score 0):

It's arguably less error-prone and potentially more efficient to let the database do this.

```
SELECT timedate, (timedate < NOW()) AS earlier, email  FROM mailer;
```

This will return a new "column" called "earlier," generated on the fly, telling you which dates are earlier with a '1' (true) or not, with a '0' (false), or NULL if timedate were null.

You can also get snazzy with a `CASE` expression, combining multiple logical tests to derive the new information.  These operations are typically extremely fast in MySQL.